# javascript if condition is not working

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to work the following code of script. but its not working. i don't know what is the problem. the x variable i created contains nothing. but still the if condition is not working. i have tried printing the x variable in an alert box and it prints nothing, which means that it contains nothing. But in its not picking up the condition don't know why. And there are no console errors.

```
<div id="test">

</div>

<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;

  if(x == '') {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'There are No friends posts yet my love!!';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable x contains not empty string but some spaces. Try to use trim() function to remove these symbols:

```
if(x.trim() == ''){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to us `if (!x) {..} ` perhaps it's undefined or null.

Comment: and can you tell me it contains spaces?? there is nothing there..how come spaces are there?

Comment: It contains newline characters. `""` is not equal to `"\n"`.

Comment: Yep not spaces but new lines because of your markup ( between <div> and </div> )

Answer (score 0):

This will work!

```
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
if(x.trim() == ''){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML='There are No friends posts yet my love!!';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use innerText

```
if(x.innerText === ''){
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4aLcfm5/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your 'x' variable is not empty. It contains two return characters. Try removing all the white-space between your open and close div statement. Here is the corrected code:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
debugger;
if(x == ''){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML='There are No friends posts yet my love!!';
}
</script>`
```

Simply add or remove returns within the div statement to see this work or not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. It all comes down to the way that your html is written:

```
<div id="test">
// This is an unnecessary space that's what is making your condition fail
</div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
if(x == ''){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML='There are No friends posts yet my 
love!!';
}
</script>
```

Clean up your html: `<div id="test"></div>`
And you don't need anything else